# Are "headBlockGauge" and "headHeaderGauge" the same?

Tags: go-ethereum, monitoring

`eth.syncing.highestBlock` is  the Highest alleged block number in the chain, and `eth.syncing.currentBlock` is the Current block number where sync is at.

Is this also true in case of `headBlockGauge` and `headHeaderGauge`?